# Как увеличить шрифт текста с помощью setState() во Flutter

Tags: flutter, setstate

Помогите мне, я новичок во Flutter. Я хочу научиться использовать метод setState(), чтобы с помощью него динамично увеличить шрифт текста?

```
setState(() {
            // какой-то код.
          });
```

Помогите мне, не могу решить данную проблему порядка двух часов))

Comment: Совет: научитесь задавать вопрос более развернуто. [Как правильно задавать вопросы](https://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html), рекомендую к прочтению.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример того как менять размер текста с помощью [setState()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html). Важно понимать что метод `setState()` сам по себе не выполняется, его кто-то должен вызвать. В данном коде это делает `onPressed:`, далее `setState()` меняет переменную `bool isSmall` с `false` на `true`, а также вызывает пересборку виджета `ChangeTextSizeTabbarState`. После чего в `labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: isSmall ? 13.0 : 22.0)` изменяется размер текста.

Также этот код можно изменить так, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку текст увеличивался на один(см. базовый пример).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: ChangeTextSizeTabbar(),
    );
  }
}

class ChangeTextSizeTabbar extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  ChangeTextSizeTabbarState createState() {
    return new ChangeTextSizeTabbarState();
  }

}

class ChangeTextSizeTabbarState extends State<ChangeTextSizeTabbar> {
  bool isSmall = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Change Text Size Tabbar Example"),
          bottom: TabBar(
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: isSmall ? 13.0 : 22.0),
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(
                text: "First Tab",
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "Second Tab",
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() => isSmall = !isSmall),
                child: Text(isSmall ? 'Make font Big' : 'Make font Small'),
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() => isSmall = !isSmall),
                child: Text(isSmall ? 'Make font Big' : 'Make font Small'),
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```